# pdblp: Return `Volume` Data from `event_type`

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi, pdblp

Is it possible to specify the columns I want to retreive for each `event_type`?

For example, `event_type` = `TRADE` returns [`Open`, `High`, `Low`, `Close`, `Volume`, `numEvents`] but I just want to see [`Volume`].

I am pulling 30days of 1 minute interval data for 30 tickers, so including these extra columns is slowing down the query.

```
end = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = end - BDay(30)
start = delta.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
interval = 1

cl1 = con.bdib('CL1 Comdty', start_datetime=start, 
         end_datetime=end, event_type='TRADE', interval=interval)
```

Is there anyway to add a `fields` parameter such as `fields = 'Volume'`?

Comment: I don't think you can - maybe try and ask the help desk.

Comment: Agree with @assylias. The docs for the API says: "Each bar contains OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME and NUMBER_OF_TICKS" implying you get all or nothing. There is no mention of getting a subset of these fields. https://data.bloomberglp.com/professional/sites/10/2017/03/BLPAPI-Core-Developer-Guide.pdf